How to add a text on line in pine script. So the text stays in the right of screen all of the time and in any timeframe
How do you add text on a line in Pinescript that stays on the right of the screen at all times and in any timeframe, similar to when we manually draw a line and add text to it on the right or left?
enter image description here

try chart.right_visible_bar_time

This will show the label on the last bar, not on the right of the screen. Also, it will move left and right if you drag the chart left or right. When you draw a line from drawing tools and text to it (right alignment), the text will be in a fixed right location regardless of whether you move or drag the chart left or right. Thank you.

You cannot perfectly do this. You just need to use an offset and update your label's x (and/or y) position on every bar.
offset = input.int(50, "Offset")

var lbl = label.new(na, na, na, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_left)

label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index + offset, close)
label.set_text(lbl, str.tostring(close, format.mintick))

